# React native confirmation code field values

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm using this package as component it shwos and get vlaues but how can I get input values from root component.

in root page

import AnimatedVerification from '../../components/AnimatedVerification/AnimatedVerification';

inside this code is all comes from this example

I just want to get this 4 number values from root component how to make it. Thank you

[Expo](https://snack.expo.io/Zil!jCFft)

[image]

/*

```
*/
import {Animated, Image, SafeAreaView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {
  CodeField,
  Cursor,
  useBlurOnFulfill,
  useClearByFocusCell,
} from 'react-native-confirmation-code-field';

import styles, {
  ACTIVE_CELL_BG_COLOR,
  CELL_BORDER_RADIUS,
  CELL_SIZE,
  DEFAULT_CELL_BG_COLOR,
  NOT_EMPTY_CELL_BG_COLOR,
} from './styles';

const {Value, Text: AnimatedText} = Animated;

const CELL_COUNT = 4;
const source = {
  uri:
    'https://user-images.gitx.com/4xxxxxxx.png',
};

const animationsColor = [...new Array(CELL_COUNT)].map(() => new Value(0));
const animationsScale = [...new Array(CELL_COUNT)].map(() => new Value(1));
const animateCell = ({hasValue, index, isFocused}) => {
  Animated.parallel([
    Animated.timing(animationsColor[index], {
      useNativeDriver: false,
      toValue: isFocused ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 250,
    }),
    Animated.spring(animationsScale[index], {
      useNativeDriver: false,
      toValue: hasValue ? 0 : 1,
      duration: hasValue ? 300 : 250,
    }),
  ]).start();
};

const AnimatedVerification = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(''); 
  const [props, getCellOnLayoutHandler] = useClearByFocusCell({
    value,
    setValue,
  });

  const renderCell = ({index, symbol, isFocused}) => {
    const hasValue = Boolean(symbol);
    const animatedCellStyle = {
      backgroundColor: hasValue
        ? animationsScale[index].interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [NOT_EMPTY_CELL_BG_COLOR, ACTIVE_CELL_BG_COLOR],
          })
        : animationsColor[index].interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [DEFAULT_CELL_BG_COLOR, ACTIVE_CELL_BG_COLOR],
          }),
      borderRadius: animationsScale[index].interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [CELL_SIZE, CELL_BORDER_RADIUS],
      }),
      transform: [
        {
          scale: animationsScale[index].interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0.2, 1],
          }),
        },
      ],
    };

    // Run animation on next event loop tik
    // Because we need first return new style prop and then animate this value
    setTimeout(() => {
      animateCell({hasValue, index, isFocused});
    }, 0);

    return (
      <AnimatedText
        key={index}
        style={[styles.cell, animatedCellStyle]}
        onLayout={getCellOnLayoutHandler(index)}>
        {symbol || (isFocused ? <Cursor /> : null)}
      </AnimatedText>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>  
      
 

      <CodeField
        ref={props.ref}
        {...props}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={setValue}
        cellCount={CELL_COUNT}
        rootStyle={styles.codeFiledRoot}
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        textContentType="oneTimeCode"
        renderCell={renderCell}
      />
   
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default AnimatedVerification;
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand, you want to get the value of the child component in parent component ?

Your `CodeField` component has a ref in the parent component `ref={props.ref}`.

In your `CodeField` component define a method who return the inputs values. And in the parent you can call the method with the ref.

Comment: In summary yes I call it from parent and childeren has inputs

Comment: Well do you have suggession